# ポインタを用いて入力されたアルファベットをアスキーコード昇順で並び替えるコード

Tags: c, ポインタ

入力されたアルファベットのランダムな文字列を、アスキーコードの昇順で並び替えて出力したいです。

**例**
元の文字列: `bfGageGaheifhalenbcuafuhneixlDbfuhflfi0`
並べ替え後: `DGGaaaaabbbceeeeffffffghhhhiiilllnnuuux`

数字が入力された時に入力を終了して出力します。

以下、自分で書いてみたのですが出力に最後の改行しか表示されません。
コードの訂正お願いします。

追記
現時点での明白なミスは修正しました。

head.next = &tail;の初期化によってうまくいかないとご意見をいただきましたが、具体的にどのように修正すればよいでしょうか。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ascii{
  int num;
  struct ascii *next;
};


int main(){
  int i;
  char c;
  struct ascii head, tail;
  head.next = &tail;
  tail.num=10000;
  for(;(i=getchar())<48 || i>57;){
    if(i==10){
      continue;
    }else{
    struct ascii *p=(struct ascii *)malloc(sizeof(struct ascii));
    p->num=i;
    struct ascii *w;
    for (w = &head; w->next != &tail;){
    if(w->next->num < p->num){
      w = w->next;
      if(w->next->num >= p->num){
    p->next=w->next;
        w->next=p;
    break;
      }
    }else{
      p->next=w->next;
    w->next=p;
    break;
    }
    }
    }
  }
  struct ascii *q;
  for(q=&head;q->next!=&tail;q=q->next){
    c=q->num;
    printf("%c", c);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(;(i=getchar())<48 && i>57;){ ...` の `&&` は `||` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: `head.next = &tail;` として初期化しているので `for (w = &head; w->next != &tail;){ ... }` の部分が一度も実行されていません。

Comment: 配列のソート用として [C library function - qsort()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) がありますので、リンクリストで実装する必要がなければこちらを使っても良いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ぱっと見 `if(i=10)` は限りなく誤りっす。 [c](/questions/tagged/c) では、等号１つ `=` は代入で、比較が欲しいのなら等号２つ `==` っす。

Answer (score 1):

今までのコメントや回答を含めてまとめると、以下のようになるでしょう。
指摘や変更内容はコメントとして記述しました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ascii {
    int num;
    struct ascii* next;
};

int main() {
    /* 以下の構造体データは全て初期化 @metropolis さん指摘関連 */
    struct ascii tail = { INT_MAX, NULL }, head = { -1, &tail };

    /* i は for の中でしか使わないので定義を移動する */
    for (int i = 0; (i = getchar()) < 48 || i > 57;) { /* @metropolis さん指摘 && -> || */
        if (i == 10) { /* @774RR さん指摘 = -> == */
            continue;
        }
        else {
            struct ascii* p = (struct ascii*)malloc(sizeof(struct ascii));
            p->num = i;
            /*
               w は for の中でしか使わないので定義を移動する。
               ループ終了判定は NULLポインタ。 @metropolis さん指摘 w->next != &tail
               次の構造体への移動はループ制御部の終端処理へ移動。w = w->next
            */
            for (struct ascii* w = &head; w->next != NULL; w = w->next) {

                /* ループ内処理は以下で十分 */
                if (w->next->num >= p->num) {
                    p->next = w->next;
                    w->next = p;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*
        q は for の中でしか使わないので定義を移動する。
        最初が &head だと最初のprintfが無効なデータになるので、head.next で初期化。
        ループ終了判定は NULLポインタ。 @metropolis さん指摘関連 w->next != &tail と同様
    */
    for (struct ascii* q = head.next; q->next != NULL; q = q->next) {

        /* c は for の中でしか使わないので定義を移動する */
        char c = q->num;
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    /* 有効な入力データが1件も無かった場合のガイド表示の考慮があればなお良いですね */
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

あなたのコードは、

`head`: ダミー要素、実際のリストに含まれる要素ではない
`tail`: 番犬要素、実際に現れうる値より大きな値(`1000`)を保持することにより終端チェックを簡略化している

と言う条件での一方向リンクトリストを作成し、新要素は常に昇順となる位置に挿入することで、常に昇順で並んだ状態にしておく、と言うものです。

初期状態

```
head           tail
+-----+-----+  +-----+-----+
| ????|&tail|->| 1000|?????|
+-----+-----+  +-----+-----+
```

最初の`bfG`を読み込んだ後

```
head           [0]            [1]            [2]            tail
+-----+-----+  +-----+-----+  +-----+-----+  +-----+-----+  +-----+-----+
| ????|&[0] |->| 'G' |&[1] |->| 'b' |&[2] |->| 'f' |&tail|->| 1000|?????|
+-----+-----+  +-----+-----+  +-----+-----+  +-----+-----+  +-----+-----+
```

(このような構造はリンクトリストとしてはよくあるものです。したがって、「`head.next = &tail;`の初期化によってうまくいかない」訳ではありません。)

この状態で'a'を読み込んだ場合、[1]の前、つまり[0]の後ろに新要素として追加しないといけません。

あなたのコードで間違っているのは、この部分で、リストが空の時、つまり`head.next = &tail;`の直後の状態では`for (w = &head; w->next != &tail;){`...`}`のfor文が一度も実行されないため、リストは空のまま、次の文字がやってきても同じで、最初が空だと永久に要素が増やされることはない、と言うコードになってしまっています。

- 新要素を挿入する位置を見つける
- その位置に新要素を追加する

と言う二種類の処理を無理にfor文の中に押し込めてしまっているので、そのようなことが発生しています。両者はきちんと分けて考えた方が良いでしょう。

```
            //新要素を挿入する位置を見つける
            //「新要素の入る位置」はリンク内の1個手前の要素が必要なので、後半の全要素出力とちょっと違う
            struct ascii *w;
            for( w = &head; w->next != &tail; w = w->next ) {
                if( w->next->num >= p->num ){
                    break;
                }
            }
            //その位置に新要素を追加する
            p->next = w->next;
            w->next = p;
```

このようにすると、for文が終了した時点で`w`が新要素を追加する位置(上の例で言うと[0])を指すことになります。また、リストが空なら`w`は先頭のダミー要素を指すので全く同じ処理で初要素を追加することができます。

また、あなたのコードではリスト内容を出力する部分にも問題があります。最初に書いたように、あなたのデータ構造では`head`はダミー要素なのにその内容を出力しますし、「`next`が`&tail`を指していない限りループ」(`q->next!=&tail`)だと、リストの最後の要素が出力されません。

その部分はこう書かないといけません。

```
    for( q = head.next; q != &tail; q = q->next ) {
        c = q->num;
        printf("%c", c);
    }
```

---

念のため、両修正を取り込んだ後のコード全体を示しておきます。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ascii {
    int num;
    struct ascii *next;
};

int main() {
    int i;
    char c;
    struct ascii head, tail;
    head.next = &tail;
    tail.num = 10000;
    for( ; (i=getchar()) < 48 || i > 57; ){
        if( i == 10 ) {
            continue;
        } else {
            struct ascii *p = (struct ascii *)malloc(sizeof(struct ascii));
            p->num = i;
            //新要素を挿入する位置を見つける
            //「新要素の入る位置」はリンク内の1個手前の要素が必要なので、後半の全要素出力とちょっと違う
            struct ascii *w;
            for( w = &head; w->next != &tail; w = w->next ) {
                if( w->next->num >= p->num ){
                    break;
                }
            }
            //その位置に新要素を追加する
            p->next = w->next;
            w->next = p;
        }
    }
    struct ascii *q;
    //全要素出力
    //先頭はダミー要素なのでその次から(`q = head.next`)、番犬要素の手前までリストの一部なので`q != &tail`
    for( q = head.next; q != &tail; q = q->next ) {
        c = q->num;
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

(余談ですが、Cで2スペインデントは殆ど見ないですね。演算子の両側に空白を置くと言うCでは非常によく普及したスペース配置のルールも守られていないのでコードが大変読みづらくなっています。もしかしたら授業(?)の先生(?)がそんなコーディングをするのかもしれませんが、できるだけ普通のCコミュニティのスタイルに合わせた方が良いですね。)

どこが本質的に必要な修正かを示すために、変数宣言などは元コードのままとしましたが、kunifさんの回答にあるように、for文の制御変数なんかは、できるだけfor文内部で宣言すると言うのがモダンなCのコーディングスタイルです。

---

余談が長くなりましたが、リンクトリストの処理では、空の場合、先頭要素の場合、末尾要素の場合などに特殊処理が必要になることがよくあります。ステップ実行トレース実行などが出来るデバッガが使えない環境でも、「空の時にどうなるか」は動きを脳内トレース出来るかと思いますので、そういう特殊ケースでどんな動作をするか、確認する癖をつけられると良いかと思います。